# How to pass a constrained string to a type using as parameters a parameter using that same constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I can build number like that:

```
type Digits = '0'| '1'| '2'| '3'| '4'| '5'| '6'| '7'| '8'| '9'
type NonZero = Exclude <Digits, '0'>
type Negative = '-'

type PositiveNumbers =
  | NonZero
  | `${NonZero}${Digits}`
  | `${NonZero}${Digits}${Digits}`
  | `${NonZero}${Digits}${Digits}${Digits}`
  | `${NonZero}${Digits}${Digits}${Digits}${Digits}`
  | `${NonZero}${Digits}${Digits}${Digits}${Digits}${Digits}`  // Error: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent.(2590)

type Numbers =
  | PositiveNumbers
  | `${Negative}${PositiveNumbers}`
```

But then i'm limited to numbers from `-99999` and `99999`, and beside that using the type `Numbers` in other types make the compiler struggle. So i'm using a type to represent numbers as a constraint like so:

```
type ConstrainNumber <N extends string> =
  N extends '0'
  ? unknown
  : N extends `${infer Char}${infer Rest}`
    ? Char extends '0'
      ? never
      : Char extends Negative
        ? ConstrainNumber <Rest>
        : ConstrainNumberRec <N, Exclude <Digits, '0'>>
    : never

type ConstrainNumberRec <S extends string, D = Digits> =
  S extends `${infer Char}${infer Rest}`
  ? Char extends D ? ConstrainNumberRec <Rest> : never
  : unknown
```

When using it on a type it works as expected:

```
type UseNumbers <N extends string & _N, _N = ConstrainNumber <N>> = N

type testValid = UseNumbers <'2875467'>
type testInvalid = UseNumbers <'02875467'> // Expected error: Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'.(2344)
```

But when i'm using a type that uses UseNumbers it breaks

```
type UseUseNumbers <N extends string & _N, _N = ConstrainNumber <N>> = 
  UseNumbers <N> // Unwanted Error: type 'N' does not satisfy the constraint 'string & ConstrainNumber<N>'
```

How can i pass a constraint string to a type using as parameters a parameter using that same constraint ?
And further more, i'm not sure to guess why it breaks ? On `UseNumbers <N>` `N` is already constraint or no ?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQYwQwO1AIwK4EsA2ATUdkFtEBTAJ1HVQGtDQAXACxhoC4AoFmgTwAdqARVAOaoaAZ1ABeUAHIADFIA%200gIwLpAJlVSAzJoAsmgKyaAbJoDsmgByaAnFPbdqAOQD2cAFokXE0AFEAHlDoyJjUADz8QqIANNJyAHwOPKBOhAKMqABu1JJSALT2SdQACi4iwlmETvhExGLiLKCgiq4eXo3NoAAGACQA3q2exC4Avv2RwiIjXR2KvQNuQ6PjgpNjfROi07Pd-YNe65tTK1HHG6tbM01ze4sHJ2sPW09nR9vXuwttw4cXr3%20-U6Ax7nIFdJogPzEYbEJh%20fxcYiEETlNygREuTDIKDI0AwUDIOCoNGcZL0RigVBiGgubxQFx4LjoQj%20WjeJGI5GEOA0AB0AAo1AYbDIAJRsUnOGokeo7UrlGiVaoEGU7eapdKK7LreUVbLK2pTGYsSEAIWQNFodG5lKkeDIqDwwkI2BpOGldVAADNhva8jYAwG8XBsIGA7F4NgiOVQlaKchynABFbqJLugaZeDUAgXPQSLRHGI8DAqCnoAyuBh8yIaMRkAIBMzeaAAMreVB2gmJ5P4tNujlIkTcy24FWemBifH0uA14gwbOW8ilkQuVhFUAAYTcs-ncAzpDCTlALJo3MwYln2YE8QkHSPJ7PYlk9iaAH4CXAKHAXAB3OAdOF738U8QzEeZsy9fMNwYYh1gg-MACVkRod4mlAd9oJgUgH1AuIXzQt8cEIbJiA6Ai4Uw7DgMfFI0gybIyII9DN23Wtd33UAwiQmtEiYtCKNYuds33JCoE4pxYgCIIQnCI5YmfeJeP4oiSIlRwWJnNjhI9UTOJbY9qNwy8k1iXgfCOG8GiafScPPT54NISi4LgSDSG4lCrmYyiDJAuyzIwwT2J0wgxK45CbzhOBiJIACPy-X9-xNMAAHVrQQBMr0pS00V7dThFAH8XGIChJzEFkeCgU9MDXNMAFUh33MRDx8mjjOTAAyUAAH0JO6o9JC3TShL3D1xMUnwnDUslkIANRgchsEkeqqg9JqpDUSwzAMXRjAsRI%202Q8A4EyebUEW0BlsazjZA2radr20BIQCCqquPaEirhAAVdSpDaqRQEwFxcW-S0RAyEQvQ4Mtpx3BdpCikipAFNQtF0XRxSS0BzUtH80tte0MqTPECzJBhLQTXFLtWrKkCREsRCm6hlqpscmqA3yL1rTLOp62Iep8QbYZGscxss0AOhZw0xsesBfHe2ESeoKQnH%20wHgdzUAwcVCGobzcsht3S1fq5onOsFrThdqQ94kKSEAAlf2geBKXRCdJ31oXQZN5M3Vy5JCZ7MQuCwmA8EIU9x1ducw4jrtMvJS0WRgSrNdD6gYYty1X0xgBBENvWQYg81IPAisIWIO3tEHNcL1NvAEZBkTEXGofyxA6ZK5iAHkEC6SWZTG8EuicLNJ3QOnMChjPhuy0hv3QoA)

Comment: It's because generic parameter defaults aren't constraints.  Your `_N` isn't constrained at all, it just defaults to `ConstainNumber<N>` but it could be `unknown` or anything.  So either you need to actually constrain `_N` (which would likely result in a circular constraint, which is apparently why you're doing this default thing in the first place), or in `UseUseNumbers` you need to write `UseNumbers<N, _N>` instead.  Nothing stops me from writing `UseUseNumbers<"hello", unknown>`. [Observe](https://tsplay.dev/mqE1dm)

Comment: @jcalz u're the man man lol :) - thanks a lot - always a response that is spot on. Beside that youre remarks holds true, but I've managed to create some utilities to play with number (adding, subtracting, multiplying, still working on dividing though) that are not limited - can actully works with number consisted of more than one hundred digits, and therefor I accept this trade off! - by the way does such a library exists ? besides being able to works with indexes on array unlimited does it have a point ? I guess I'm asking if it would be a good publish or no ?

Comment: Maybe look in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382 and/or https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42938 to see if people have published a library?  There's also the declined https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47141 . Opinion: I think such a library is a fun idea but mostly just a fun idea and not anything I'd necessarily want to subject real world code to.

Comment: @jcalz in [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBjynN) that makes the type you created, while not complaining a `never` - juste updated `UseNumbers` to `unknown extends _N ? never : N`. I don't see how to make better trying to represent numbers as string in a type that won't make the compiler struggle.

Comment: I think it's unlikely you need to harden your code against unexpected specifications of `_N`; it's just that the compiler cannot assume that `_N` is equal to its default.  Anyway I'm going to write up an answer to the main question.

Comment: @jcalz once I've finished division and fully find the best solution to the exposed matter after browsing your links -hopefully u'll review the lib ;). Tanks again for your knowledge and your willingness to share it. Big up ^^

Comment: @jcalz [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAjK4W) works in most case - only accepted second parameters would be the same string and then it would evaluate to `never` - sufficient trade off I believe ;)

Comment: @jcalz how would you document that a parmeter is not intended to be used ? some thing like `* @param _A internal to ensure input is valid - do not use` ?

Comment: Possibly? I think initial underscore also tends to give that impression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) are not [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints):

```
type Foo<T extends number> = T;
type BadFoo = Foo<string>; // error, not satisfying constraint

type Bar<T = number> = T;
type DefaultBar = Bar; // number
type StillGoodBar = Bar<string>; // string
```

In the above, the type parameter `T` in `Foo` is *constrained* to `number`, while in `Bar` it is unconstrained but just *defaults* to `number`.  So you can't write `Foo<string>`.  If you just write `Bar` it will be `Bar<number>`, but nothing stops someone from writing `Bar<string>`.  It's not an error, and the compiler cannot assume inside `Bar` that `T` will be a subtype of `number`.

---

In this definition,

```
type UseUseNumbers<N extends string & _N, _N = ConstrainNumber<N>> = ...
```

The `_N` type parameter is unconstrained.  It can be anything at all, even though it *defaults* to `ConstrainNumber<N>`.  Only `N` is constrained to `string & _N`.

Your primary use case here is that nobody specifies `_N`, and that `UseUseNumbers<N>` is equivalent to `UseUseNumbers<N, ConstrainNumber<N>>`, which compiles if and only if `N extends string & ConstrainNumber<N>`.  That's a neat way to avoid the circularity constraint error that would happen if you wrote `type Oopsie<N extends string & ConstrainNumber<N>>`, but that trick only works by leaving open the possibility that `_N` does not depend on `N`.

And so the compiler cannot *know* that `_N` is anything in particular.  Some rogue developer might write `UseUseNumbers<string, unknown>` or `UseUseNumbers<"abc","abc" | "def">` or some other crazy off-label use of `UseUseNumbers` that happens to compile.  This is probably unavoidable (although the avoidability or lack thereof is off-topic for the question) but also unlikely to actually happen especially if you document that `_N` is for "internal use only" (but again, off-topic).  How much you want to account for this possibility is up to you.

---

Anyway, the compiler is upset with

```
type UseUseNumbers<N extends string & _N, _N = ConstrainNumber<N>> =
  UseNumbers<N> // <-- error
```

Why? because `UseNumbers<N>` evaluates to `UseNumbers<N, ConstrainNumber<N>>` which (similarly to `UseUseNumbers`) only compiles if `N extends string & ConstrainNumber<N>`.  But the compiler doesn't know what about the current `N`, which is only known to extend `string & _N`, and `_N` is unconstrained.  So it doesn't compile.

---

The way to fix this is to just explicitly take the assumption that nobody's going to mess with `_N` in `UseUseNumbers`, and pass this down into `UseNumbers`:

```
type UseUseNumbers<N extends string & _N, _N = ConstrainNumber<N>> =
  UseNumbers<N, _N> // <-- this fixes it
```

Since the `_N` in `UseNumbers` is unconstrained, you can write `UseNumbers<N, _N>`, which will compile if and only if `N extends string & _N`.  But we know that's true by definition of `N` in `UseUseNumbers`.  As long as people write `UseUseNumbers<N>` and do not pass a second type argument, then this will evaluate to `UseNumbers<N>` as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFShAHsCA7AJgZymwFcBbAIwgCcA+KAXimQG4AoUSKAIQENd44DWAkT5gVAJbYA5jWZQA9ArRUqcKgBoicYFHw9gE-ADMQU6VADGcbGKo8pwVu3DReVFEJIVqdRixdOABEIYx5iABtgdyF3eSUiMkoqQOgAZUMIiIBxBFwYxndRcXM5RWU7c2cOaCCJaQlgQkYAcgAGFqgAHygWgEZOnpaAJkHegGYxloAWKYBWKYA2KYB2KYAOKYBOFtSoADkbAC1qQUYAUXRLCOJcCEQ6hqatdpaaPf2IaQMJADdoVoAWl2ewAwjY7A5sPsktREPs0JgcAQ9CUZH5WFADoisHhCK9MVAAPxQYjYADW2DgAHdsISAFzYjC4lEAAwAJABvKTGahQUEACx4VAAvlyeXyAEoQMQi1mEkmC4U45H4joKogQf4pLGMpVUFV4g5fH7-DXg2ziKEwnweaVid66-kQq1SG3JaWWeFaS7XW73R6NfAvDo0R1QRnYLXUaquZ2W+xu2FUT2INKGlGVGRaIJCQNNDFY9PM1VQDnc7C8g36sUVqtQe3AOXmoUGktG3OKl2J6HJ1ONuiR6M6iOkilU2nOPYAVXwEHd1Hw8IzhCzFgAZFAAPr7LQ7oQWyFJ23wsNCfaxziziDXhdUJcI9uZtEb7e7t8H7vW5OnwtQW-Jg+e77HQCSIICgJQMAApGFAxgSOgMpQI0l7QAAakI14AbaS4AEQChAIC4VoZKUjS2CgcoVLQeYqJwGAhA0fgQA)